# malloc(sizeof(struct element) * size); or malloc(sizeof(struct element) * 1);

Tags: c

I read such a snippet code from [6.6.  Arrays and Pointers](http://www.it.uc3m.es/pbasanta/asng/course_notes/dynamic_memory_arrays_and_pointers_en.html)

```
struct element 
{
  float number1;
  int number2;
  char letter;
};

struct element *table;

table = (struct element *)malloc(sizeof(struct element) * size);
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{
  table[i].number1 = 0.0;
  table[i].number2 = 10;
  table[i].letter = 'B';
}
```

Reference to `table = (struct element *)malloc(sizeof(struct element) * size);`, I am confuse with additional `*size`:

`struct element` has an explicit of its size of 3

```
{
  float number1;
  int number2;
  char letter;
};
```

If `*size`, it should be 3*3 memory spaces are set aside.

I guess it should be a simple `table = (struct element *)malloc(sizeof(struct element) 1);`

What's the problem with my deduction?

Comment: If you want more than one, you need to multiply with how many you want.

Comment: but table[] is one element. @molbdnilo

Comment: @riderdragon, `size` is a misnomer in this example. It should be something like `recordCount`.

Comment: Does 'table = malloc(sizeof *table * size);' make more sense for you?

Comment: The code is creating an array of several `struct element`s and pointing `table` at the first one in the array. `size` is  the number of array elements. `sizeof(struct element)` is the size of the individual array elements.

Comment: @riderdragon, `table = (struct element *)malloc(sizeof(struct element) 1);` would yield a syntax error. Perhaps you meant `table = (struct element *)malloc(sizeof(struct element) * 1);`? But then that's just wasted code. `1 * sizeof(struct element) == sizeof(struct element)`.

Comment: could  you explain it? it seem very tricky `table = malloc(sizeof *table * size)` @chux

Comment: @riderdragon, you also seem to be confusing struct field count with table element count, they are not the same thing. `sizeof(struct element) == sizeof(float) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(char) + sizeof(unknown number padding bytes)`.

Comment: @riderdragon It's just like the real world. If you want to make room for five boxes of chocolate, you need a space of size `5 * (size of one box of chocolates)`.

Comment: @riderdragon, the main problem with the sited example is that it is not an [mcve]. The `size` variable is not defined.

Comment: 'sizeof *table' is the size of one piece of data that 'table' points to.  'size' is the number of _data_ desired. So in total, multiply those together to get the number of bytes needed for the allocation.

Comment: smart, so it's universal and not bothered to do casing. Is it an accepted practice or just for illustration. @chux

Comment: In C, the cast is not necessary. If you enjoy typing and want others to enjoy typing maintaining the code, use a cast. Otherwise to code tight, make easier to review and maintain, drop the cast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, `table` is an array of `element`.  In this case, `size` is not the size of `element` but rather how many `elements` are in the array (or in other words, length of the array).

This is a really good example of why it's important to name your variables properly.  In this case, `size` is not the best name for this variable, something like `count` or `num_elements` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Is it not required to declare "size" or "count"  in advance?

Comment: It is, the example omitted it for some reason, which makes it incomplete.

Comment: @riderdragon Examples usually don't include all the bookkeeping details. The author is assuming that you're capable of filling in the missing details if you want to actually compile the code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think you are confused with the use of `size` in this line

`table = (struct element *)malloc(sizeof(struct element) * size);`

`size` here refers to how many entries of type struct element you wish to store?

If I want to store two such entries then my `size` will be 2. If `size` is 1 then space for only one entry will be provided. Each entry will have space for `one integer, one float and one character`. This `size` has nothing to do with the what is there inside the structure.